# iterate hasmap with ng-repeat. Hashmap with array as value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can i iterate below JSON response from server using angularJS on UI using ng-repeat?

```
$scope.data = {
  "Home Needs": [{
    "id": 11,
    "itemName": "PARLE G 500 Grams",
    "itemPrice": 50,
    "minSellPrice": 45,
    "discount": 0,
    "store": "Home Needs"
  }],
  "SRI SAI Store": [{
    "id": 1,
    "itemName": "PARLE G 500 Grams",
    "itemPrice": 50,
    "minSellPrice": 45,
    "discount": 0,
    "store": "SRI SAI Store"
  }],
  "Ashirwad": [{
    "id": 10,
    "itemName": "PARLE G 500 Grams",
    "itemPrice": 50,
    "minSellPrice": 46,
    "discount": 0,
    "store": "Ashirwad"
  }]
}
```

Can anyone help me with a jsfiddle please or a pointer please?

thanks

Comment: can you tell me how exactly you want to display this ??

Comment: @AhmedEid - Hi, I want to display Store Name as tiitle and then sum of all price of all items as total cart value of one store and rest of the information like item name and individual price below as a list. can u pls help me with that?

Comment: Just like Flash replied :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kindly check [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spqkfa67/)

```
<div ng-app>
     <div ng-controller="ClickToEditCtrl">
          <p>Your Data:</p>
         <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
          name: {{key}}
        <li ng-repeat="v in value">
            {{v.id}},
            {{v.itemName}},
            {{v.itemPrice}},
            {{v.minSellPrice}},
            {{v.discount}},
            {{v.store}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

you can modified as u required. I hope this might help.

Comment: also, can we have one {{total}} shown on UI which will have some of all items related to one store????

Comment: @AngryJS what exactly do u want? if u want u can do `{{v.itemPrice + v.minSellPrice}}` some manipulation in that

Comment: Thanks Flash, I want to show a Total Cart Value = {{ invoiceTotal }} where which will sum all minSellprice of all items related to same store .. same way how u have shown but with an additional attribute which will add.